# Can general BT4.0 adapters understand RSSI?

Tags: bluetooth

Im working with BLE beacons and Raspberry Pi 3B+ to read their signals, and its working quite well with the RPi built-in bluetooth, bluez and noble library.

The problem is when i try to use an external adapter instead of the onboard. I disabled onboard bluetooth by adding to config.txt file:

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

and i disable the hciuart service as well.
With the BT dongle running as my bt controller, i can scan and find nearer beacons using bluetoothctl tools, but nothing about the RSSI. I tried to use js library noble and python library bluepy but its always returns a RSSI of 0.

Could the dongle be missing some part of the packets? Has anyone had success scanning for BLE devices and RSSi using external adapters?

The adapter is identified by lsusb as Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode).

Pics of bluetoothctl scanning with built-in BT and external BT:[Dongle scanning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sJE2.png)
[Onboard scanning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV5fA.png)

Appreciate any help.